# Running invoke-sqlcmd within Terraform

Tags: azure, powershell, terraform, azure-sql-database, terraform-provider-azure

I have created this in terraform - I am trying to do some sql commands on the SQL Server after its been built and it runs at the correct time. I cannot really use a username and password to execute the Invoke-sqlcmd and why should i when the Terraform is running with the correct account.

Here is my code :

```
resource "null_resource" "create-sql-user" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
    Install-Module -Name SqlServer -Force
     Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "CREATE LOGIN [azSG-ATP-Users-${var.environment}] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER" -ConnectionString "Server=tcp:sqlsvr-${lower(var.locationname)}-${lower(var.resourcename)}-${lower(var.environment)}.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Master;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;" 
    EOT
      
  

    interpreter = ["pwsh", "-Command"]
  }

  depends_on = ["azurerm_sql_firewall_rule.main"]
}
```

I cannot use the authetication part of the connection string to use Integrated Security as its not allowed. I have been struggling for days on this.

Any ideas or working examples on this subject.

I am getting the error :

```
 Login failed for user ''.
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better ask whoever wrote the policy that doesn't allow Integrated Security about this? Surely they must have a better answer for what the appropriate alternative method of authentication is :)

Answer (score 0):

It's Azure SQL Database.  Windows Integrated Security doesn't work.  [ActiveDirectoryIntegrated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15) is an AAD auth method, and may work, but Invoke-SqlCmd doesn't expose that method.  The simplest solution here is to use an [AccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps#example-11--connect-to-azure-sql-database--or-managed-instance--using-an-access-token).