Terraform SQLCMD and ServicePrincipal
I'm trying to let my terraform configuration to run following three sqlcmd commands
sqlcmd -S myserver.database.windows.net -d master --authentication-method ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal -Q "CREATE LOGIN [user@example.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;"
sqlcmd -S myserver.database.windows.net -d somedb --authentication-method ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal -Q "CREATE USER [user@example.com] FOR LOGIN [user@example.com];"
sqlcmd -S myserver.database.windows.net -d somedb --authentication-method ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal -Q "ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [user@example.com];"

These environment variables:

SQLCMDUSER
SQLCMDPASSWORD
ARM_CLIENT_ID
ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
ARM_TENANT_ID
AZURE_CLIENT_ID
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET
AZURE_TENANT_ID

are set correctly. One of many approaches was using
resource "terraform_data" "configure_sql_access" {
  triggers_replace = [
    module.mssqlsrv,
    module.sqldb_for_service
  ]

  for_each = var.env_features["awi"] ?  { for obj in local.required_db : obj.db_name => obj } : {}

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      c:/tools/sqlcmd -S ${module.mssqlsrv[0].fully_qualified_domain_name} -d master --authentication-method ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal -Q "CREATE LOGIN [${each.value.awi_name}] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;"
    EOT
  }
}

which fails with an error

Error running command '      c:/tools/sqlcmd -S myserver.database.windows.net -d master --authentication-method ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal -Q "CREATE LOGIN [user@example.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;"
│ ': exit status 1. Output: Sqlcmd: 'LOGIN': Unknown command. Enter '--help' for command help.

Running the same command from the output in the same cmd session, works without an issue.
What am I doing wrong?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70610815/running-invoke-sqlcmd-within-terraform
Check this once


Error running command Output: Sqlcmd: 'LOGIN': Unknown command. Enter '--help' for command help.

The issue might be with the special characters included in the sqlcmd while passing it. Each local-exec provisioner executes in its own unique shell environment and also reads the command and special characters differently.
In order to read them correctly using terraform without any conflict, escape them with double backslashes so that they can be properly passed to the command under local-exec.
And also check if the environment variables are properly set in the environment. Alternatively, you can also use environment{} block under provisioner to set environment variables for local-exec part.
Refer SO for the similar approach on setting it up.
Add the below block in your local-exec and execute the code.
environment = { 
  SQLCMDUSER = "" 
  SQLCMDPASSWORD = "*****" 
  ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID = "" 
  ARM_TENANT_ID = "Tenant_ID"
 }

Mentioning the above, I have modified command syntax as below.
provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      c:/tools/sqlcmd -S ${azurerm_mssql_server.example.name}.database.windows.net
 -d master --authentication-method ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal -Q "CREATE LOGIN \\[${xxxx}\\] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;"
    EOT
  }


